# Laravel mass update , still fire event

Tags: laravel, eloquent

As stated in the doc, laravel will not fire an event on mass update/insert/delete.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#events

It uses the Builder for this and will not fire an event.

Is there a way that I can still fire an event after a mass update for example?   I would only need the query Builder to extract the needed info myself ( log purposes).

Comment: check this... https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/trigger-events-on-batch-insertupdatedelete

Comment: @VikashPathak : thanks , I found that one , but how would I implement this in a model?  So it fires an event when the query builder Update() has been called.  Eg: $model->where(something)->update([]); >> fire event.

Comment: If you would like to do for the batch request...you will have to fire custom event.

Answer (score 3):

It is actually possible , but you have to extend the Eloquent builder ,overwrite the update/insert methods and send the event there. 
Just been playing around with it...  Needs work, but the basic idea is the following :

```
class Test extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public $dispatchesEvents = [
        'saved' => SavedTest::class
    ];


    /**
     * INCLUDE this as a trait in your model.
     * Overwrite the eloquentBuilder.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder  $query
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|static
     */
    public function newEloquentBuilder($query)
    {

        return new TestBuilder($query);
    }


}
```

Extend the eloquent builder...

```
class TestBuilder extends Builder
{

    /**
     * Update a record in the database and fire event.
     *
     * @param  array  $values
     * @return int
     */
    public function update(array $values)
    {

        // normal eloquent behavior.
        $result =$this->toBase()->update($this->addUpdatedAtColumn($values));

        /*
         * Fire event.
         */
        if($result){
            if( $event = Arr::get($this->model->dispatchesEvents,'saved')){

                 // at the attributes.
                $this->model->fill($this->addUpdatedAtColumn($values));

                $queryBuilder =$this->toBase();

                event(new $event($this->model,$queryBuilder));
            }

        }

    }

    public function insert(array $values)
    {

       // same idea..
    }
}
```

The event class :

```
class SavedTest
{
    use SerializesModels;
    public $model;
    public $query;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($model,$query =null)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
        $this->query = $query;
    }


}
```

The listener.

```
class SavedTestEvent
{


    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * 
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  object  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle($event)
    {

        // The model , with the attributes.
        dump($event->model);

       // the query builder , you could extract the wheres or whatever to build your own log for it.
      dump($event->query); 


    }
}
```

Comment: Can we get the primary key or other parameters used while updating the records ?

Answer (score 0):

@Paolo on batch request it would not be file the event you must have to perform operation on single record.. like

```
Analytic::where('id', '>', 100)->get()->each(function($analytic) {
    $analytic->delete();
});
```

Comment: @Paolo_Mulder does this helpful?

Comment: @Viksah Pathak : thanks for your reply mate , but that would mean to change a lot of code on a current project.  I managed to extend the idea I posted below and it works perfectly and it reduced a lot of queries.  So far so good, still testing all possible problems.

Comment: This solution might take a long long time if there are a lot of records in table, say a million rows. You may event get out of memory error you may use chunkById to check memory issue, but it will take a huge amount of time .